# How to calculate the hours within an interval

Tags: sql, expression, reportbuilder3.0

We are building a report using ReportBuilder 3.0. In our database we have a start time and end time on a job being performed. In ReportBuilder 3.0 we would like to create a field that shows how much of the work time is within a certain interval.

Example: start time: 20.00 - End time: 04.30 +1... how much is in the interval between 22.00 to 06.00 +1 = 6,5 hours.

Does any one have a good example on how to create an expression that would give the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
differnce(new Date(dayear,damonth-1,dadate),new Date(endyear,endmonth-1,enddate))
```